# About Android Init Language to start a daemon dynamically after devices was added when phone booting process

Tags: android, linux

I want to start a native service daemon, when my device is decteded(i.e. the devices is create at boot time). I saw the android init.rc document and got this grammer:

```
device-removed-<path>   Triggers of these forms occur when a device node is added or removed.
```

So I think I can use this grammer to start my daemon. Then I modify init.rc as below,

```
on device-added-/dev/fp_dev
      setprop fp.hardware.vendor llc
      start fpDaemon

#Finger Feature for llc
service fpDaemon /system/bin/gxFpDaemon
     disabled
     user system
     group system
```

Above grammer means, when my device name (`fp_dev` for example) was added when booting time, I start the native service daemon. But, the problem is the device is added when booted, but the daemon is not started as required. what's wrong with this?  Many thinks.

Comment: I am looking for the reason for this, I found the device `fp_dev` is created before init.rc parsed, so that the action was not triggerd. Question is: how to trigger the on device-added-<dev-path>? any one has some clue?

Comment: the post `http://grokbase.com/t/gg/android-porting/12a9arqyc5/question-about-on-device-added`, gave us an answer that, it is a classic vaporware.